# silverlight build a datagrid in the code behind

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Is it possible in a Silverlight DataGrid to have a column that has rows with different types of controls?  For instance the first two rows of the column should be text, the next two rows would have buttons and then the next 6 rows would have Checkboxes.  I need to build it in the code behind also.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the replies all. Turns out I used a component one Flex Grid to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the code below code gives you the idea.

```
        foreach (var item in ItemList)
        {
            //Row definition and column definitions are similar
            LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() 
            { Height = GridLength.Auto});         

            HelloObject hl=new HelloPObject();

            //Attached property imeplemantation
            Grid.SetRow(hl,Layout2.RowDefinitions.Count);

            //You may add any UIElement as Children
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(hl);                
        }
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't realize datagrid.

Ok its possible for datagrid also ,
AFAIK Telerik's radgridview gives you the index of row .But you can manage by yourself.

Beside this when you hit grids ordering this order may be lost depending on your sortingmemberpath of column. But you can switch your CellTemplate depending a property in DataGrid's ItemsSource elements.

```
 DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
        int rowNdx = 0;
        grid.LoadingRow += (s, a) =>
            {                    
                DataGridCell cell = myList.Columns[0].GetCellContent(a.Row).Parent as DataGridCell;
                switch (rowNdx)
                {
                    case 0:
                        cell.Content = new TextBlock() { Text= "Click" };
                        break;
                    default:
                        cell.Content = new Button() { Content = "Click" };                    
                        break;
                }
                rowNdx++;                    
            };
```

Comment: That might work for me, but I do have one question.  Is it possible to do this in a datagrid in the code behind?